# Current State of Knowledge: Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

'The Zeta-Function by Riemann' by Titchmarsh is supposed to give a detailed account upon the topic around the Riemann Hypothesis.
However, this book was written in 1930, and I have not looked it up.

I have shortly tried to find something more recent upon the topic, as I wondered what the current main believe is how this problem might be solved, or if some convincing evidence was found that the hypothesis is indeed correct, or even incorrect.

How does it stand, or have mathematicians by now mostly gave up, until someone makes a breakthrough achivement?

Comment: Here are some notes from 2010: https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01770

Comment: There are a ton of books that are more recent (Ivic and Karatsuba Voronin in addition to the revised Titchmarsh) while the two volumes of Broughan are probably the best reference for current approaches

Comment: the word is "breakthrough" as opposed to your  brakethrough

Comment: The vast majority of the mathematicians is convinced of the truth of the Riemann hypothesis although there are some doubts collected [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2109509_On_some_reasons_for_doubting_the_Riemann_hypothesis) , but they are apparently not taken very serious. The proof of the Riemann hypothesis appears to be out of reach.

Comment: Of course , there are several indications that the Riemann hypothesis is probably true. Wikipedia gives a good survey of them.

Comment: There is a related question on MO:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96642/current-status-of-the-riemann-hypothesis